# Improving insertion time of a hash table - C++

Tags: c++, hashtable

I'm working on a hash table for a class, and I'm trying to improve the insertion speed. In my implementation, I'm using chaining. A vector hosts lists of strings. I have to insert over 350,000 words into the hash table, from a dictionary (the "words" from /usr/share/dict/words for my college's CS department).

Here's my hash table. Any strange naming conventions are likely required by the assignment (e.g. MyDS):

```
#ifndef _MYDS_H
#define _MYDS_H

#include "MyHash.h"
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class MyDS
{
public:
    MyDS()
    {
        max_size = 128;
        size = 0;
        nodes.resize(max_size);
    }

// destructor

// copy constructor

// assignment operator

    void push(const string& s)
        {
            unsigned long hash = MyHash()(s) % max_size;
            list<string> & hashList = nodes[hash];

            hashList.push_back(s);

            if (++size > nodes.size())
            {
                max_size *= 4;
                rehash();
            }
        }

bool search(const string& s)
{
    unsigned long hash = MyHash()(s) % max_size;
    list<string>::iterator it = nodes[hash].begin();

    for (int i = 0; i < nodes[hash].size(); i++)
    {
        if (*it == s)
        {
            return true;
        }
        *it++;
    }

    return false;
}
private:
    void rehash()
    {
        unsigned long hash;
        list<string>::iterator it;
        vector < list<string> > newNodes = nodes;
        newNodes.resize(max_size);

        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.size(); i++)
        {
            if (nodes[i].size() > 0)
            {
                it = nodes[i].begin();
                hash = MyHash()(*it) % max_size;
                newNodes[hash] = nodes[i];
            }
        }

        nodes = newNodes;
    }

    vector< list<string> > nodes;
    int max_size;
    int size;
};

#endif
```

The hash function I'm using is djb2. My search function and insert both seem to be very quick. It's the rehashing that's taking a long time.

If there's a better way to set up my hash table, let me know. I'm not restricted in terms of what data structures I use to do this project.

Comment: You are *copying* an awful lot.

Comment: You could store items as pairs of the hash (the raw, unmodded number) and the item in each bucket, so there's no rehashing to be done? Just re-read the stored hash, mod it against the new max size and redistribute.

Comment: The number of *collisions* or rehashes depend on the hashing function.  You need to choose between quick function and many rehashes or longer execution function and less collisions.

Comment: are you sure you should increment side of nodes on each push? Nodes is per hash chain

Comment: You can/should rewrite `search` to be less noisy: `bool search(const string & s) { auto & bucket = nodes[MyHash()(s) % max_size]; return bucket.end() != std::find(bucket.begin(), bucket.end(), s); }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stop copying all those strings just to watch them burn a minute later. Try this instead:

```
void rehash()
{
    std::vector<std::list<std::string>> newNodes(max_size);

    for (auto & bucket : nodes)
    {
        for (auto it = bucket.begin(); it != bucket.end(); )
        {
            std::list<std::string> & newBucket = newNodes[MyHash()(*it) % max_size];
            newBucket.splice(newBucket.end(), bucket, it++);
        }
    }

    nodes.swap(newNodes);
}   //    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This also fixes your broken "rehashing" that didn't actually rehash.

Comment: I didn't even know about std::move, that's really useful. Thanks!

Comment: @user1888527: Actually, it's not even the best approach here. I changed it to resplice list nodes directly, which saves you *all* allocations.

Comment: That is _much_ faster than my original "method." Thanks for showing me some new things I wasn't aware of before!

Answer (score 1):

```
    if (nodes[i].size() > 0)
    {
        it = nodes[i].begin();
        hash = MyHash()(*it) % max_size;
        newNodes[hash] = nodes[i];
    }
```

I think these are incorrect.
The elements in nodes[i] should be distributed into different nodes in the larger table.
So, you need to re-calculate the hash for each element, rather than only the first one.

Comment: Good point! I had an erroneous line of thinking that resulted in that, and neglected to notice it afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to rehash everything whenever the amount of nodes is equal to size. On a side note you increment size whenever you add a string to the table, so even if one bucket has a list of 128 strings in it and all other buckets are still empty you resize the amount of buckets, are you sure that is the logic you intended? I'd recommend allocating around square root of n buckets, and not rehashing at all. If you're using a good hash function the distribution of strings into buckets will be fairly even and lookup times will not suffer much at all.

Answer (score 0):

"if there's a better way to set up my hash table, let me know. I'm not restricted in terms of what data structures I use to do this project."

In that case use an existing hashmap like std::unordered_map or std::hash_map. I am sure you will get failing grade in class, but you will get passing grade in real life

Comment: Funny, but I get bonus points if my data structure is quicker than those!

Comment: i will be stunned if you can build something faster than the standard containers. Hopefully you will do a side by side compare - thats extra credit

Comment: Side by side comparison is already part of the assignment, unfortunately. I'll fight my hardest for these extra five points though.